# Fuchsia buds are dropping

Tags: houseplants, flowers, indoors, flowering

My Fuchsia is indoor, it's a small plant and looks quite healthy with so many buds.

However, I for last 2-3 days the buds are dropping if I am touching the plant.

Watering conditions:

1. Plenty of holes in the pot
2. I usually tend to water when the surface is dry.

Fertilizing conditions:

1. I use liquid fertilizer (COMPO Blumendunger) twice a week as per instruction.

Wind, Sun and temperature

1. No wind as it is indoor.
2. It gets morning sun usually.
3. Temperature is approx. 20 degrees Centigrade (68F).

Other

1. No Bugs or anything else.

Should I be worried or it's normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you said you repotted this plant - it may be a reaction to that, but fuchsias in the house are a bit fussy. Over or underwatering can cause bud drop, along with too much sun (they prefer dappled sunlight orlight shade rather than direct sun, especially through a window) or sometimes they'll react like this from just rotating the pot. Just keep it watered when it needs it, and hopefully more buds will form.